# Is the trace of this operator finite?

Tags: functional-analysis, operator-theory, hilbert-spaces, banach-spaces, trace

Let $H$ Hilbert space and let $Q\colon H \to H$ be a linear, self-adjoint, positive, trace-class operator. Let $X\colon H \to H$ be a linear, self-adjoint, positive operator. Does it follow then that $$Tr(QX) < \infty ?$$